# RMagick + Ubuntu - wrong jpeg library?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm having an issue getting RMagick to behave on Ubuntu Intrepid. RMagick installed correctly, but when I attempt to use the JPEG manipulation functions, I get the following error:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError 
(Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80
```

However, when I look in /usr/local/lib, I see libjpeg.so.8.0.2 is installed. Where should I go from here? I can't find any documentation on this issue anywhere on the 'net. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install it? If you install from the Ubuntu package manager, it goes into /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8.0.2. Try `sudo apt-get install libjpeg8`.

Comment: libjpeg8 isn't a registered package. The package that is needed is libjpeg8-dev. This package is available for Ubuntu 10.10, but doesn't seem to be in the package lists for the server's current version (8.10 Intrepid). Is there a way that I can pull this package from the other repository, or do I need to upgrade my server to make it work?

Comment: OK, thanks for putting me on the right track. I had compiled a newer version of ImageMagick than was necessary. I removed the compiled version, and used the package version (apt-get install imagemagick libmagick9-dev). That works with the older version of the javascript library. Have a good day. Thanks.